# Не правильно работает перемножение матриц в классе, в чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: c++

Почему не перемножает матрицы? Пробовал передавать сразу 3 параметра(матрицы A,B,C), все равно внутрь цикла не заходит и выводит ошибку segmentation fault, или ‘matrixMultiplic’ was not declared in this scope.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Matrix {
public:
  int sizeMatrix; // матрица квадратная
  T **matrix;

public:
  Matrix() {
    sizeMatrix = 0;

    matrix = new T *[sizeMatrix];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++) {
      matrix[i] = new T[sizeMatrix];
    }
  }
  Matrix(int sizeMatrix) {

    this->sizeMatrix = sizeMatrix;

    matrix = new T *[sizeMatrix];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++) {
      matrix[i] = new T[sizeMatrix];
    }
  }

  void fillMatrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < sizeMatrix; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = (random() % 100) / 2.5;
      }
    }
  }

  Matrix matrixMultiplic(Matrix<T> &A, Matrix<T> &B) {

    if (A.sizeMatrix != B.sizeMatrix) {
      cout
          << "Количество столбцов матрицы A не равно количеству строк матрицы B"
          << endl;
      return -1;
    }
    Matrix<T> C(sizeMatrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++) {
      cout << i << endl;
      for (int j = 0; j < sizeMatrix; j++) {
        C.matrix[i][j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeMatrix; k++) {
        C.matrix[i][j] += A.matrix[i][k] * B.matrix[k][j];
        }
      }
    }
    return C;
  }

  void printMatrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeMatrix; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < sizeMatrix; j++) {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
};


int main() {

  Matrix<int> A(3);
  A.fillMatrix();
  Matrix<int> B(3);
  B.fillMatrix();

  A.printMatrix();
  B.printMatrix();

  Matrix<int> C();

  C = matrixMultiplic(A, B);

}
```

Comment: Гм, первая ошибка — времени выполнения, вторая — времени компиляции. Так у вас код компилируется или нет? Тот кусок, что вы предоставили — несомненно, не компилируем... Сделайте нормальный компилируемый пример, если можно. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Код не компилируется в обоих случаях, если передавать в перемножение матриц 3 параметра A,B,C и изменять матрицу С в функции или же возвращать перемноженную матрицу, как в данном примере. Обновил код, это все что у меня есть на данный момент

Comment: *это все что у меня есть на данный момент* - не надо вываливать весь свой код сюда. Если бы вы потрудились составить [mcve], то проблема наверняка бы стала очевидна и вопрос бы не понадобился.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с мелочей — не `random()`, а `rand()`. Ваша функция `matrixMultiplic` — член класса, значит, должна предваряться именем объекта с точкой. Объявление `Matrix<int> C();` — это объявление *функции*, возвращающей `Matrix`... Конструктор по умолчанию пытается выделять нулевого размера память. Нет нормального деструктора, копирующего конструктора и т.п. — а значит, проблемы с памятью неизбежны! Явно это не все, что-то я пропустил, но это бросается в глаза.

Ну, а само умножение... Я бы сделал его оператором вне класса, примерно так —

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator *(const Matrix<T> &A, const Matrix<T> &B)
{
    if (A.sizeMatrix != B.sizeMatrix) throw("Количество столбцов матрицы A не равно количеству строк матрицы B");

    Matrix<T> C(A.sizeMatrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.sizeMatrix; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.sizeMatrix; j++)
        {
            C.matrix[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < A.sizeMatrix; k++) {
                C.matrix[i][j] += A.matrix[i][k] * B.matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

Раз уж у вас все члены открыты...

Ну, а в коде `main`

```
Matrix<int> C;
C = A*B;
C.printMatrix();
```

Вот только еще раз — без *правильных* конструктора копирования, оператора присваивания и деструктора — все это работать нормально не будет!

Comment: Спасибо! По поводу открытых переменных - забыл поставить private, деструктор есть. Но такой вопрос, зачем нам нужен здесь конструктор копирования, что он нам даст и зачем нам создавать дубликат матрицы, если можно просто создать еще одну переменную.

Comment: Потому что у вас динамическая память. Если не создать конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания — копироваться будут указатели. Два разных объекта будут указывать на одну память. Не будет деструктора — будет утечка памяти, будет деструктор — двойное освобождение. Да и без этого — меняете элемент в одной матрице, а он меняется и в другой...